# Displaying multiple tags in MathJax HTML

Tags: html, mathjax

Im trying to display LaTeX equation as a sytem, with individual equation has its own numbering, using MathJax in an HTML file. While doing this, I got the error saying "Multiple \tag" for the following script.

```
            $$ \begin{cases} {}
            a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+a_{13}x_3 = b_1 \\ \tag{eq:1a}
            a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+a_{23}x_3 = b_2 \\ \tag{eq:1b}
            a_{31}x_1+a_{32}x_2+a_{33}x_3 = b_3,   \tag{eq:1c}
          \end{cases}$$
```

I'm importing MathJax to display LaTeX with the following script in HTML.

```
    <script>
      MathJax = {
        tex: {
          inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
          tags: 'ams'
        }
      };
    </script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async
        src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `cases` environment doesn't allow tags within it in LaTeX, and in MathJax the tag actually is aligned to the equation as a whole, so only one allowed.

You probably want the `numcases` environment that is in the `cases` MathJax package.

```html
<script>
MathJax = {
  loader: {load: ['[tex]/empheq', '[tex]/cases']},
  tex: {
    packages: {'[+]': ['empheq', 'cases']}
  }
};
</script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml.js" defer id="MathJax-script"></script>

$$
\begin{numcases}{}
            a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+a_{13}x_3 = b_1 \tag{eq:1a} \\
            a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+a_{23}x_3 = b_2 \tag{eq:1b} \\
            a_{31}x_1+a_{32}x_2+a_{33}x_3 = b_3 \tag{eq:1c}
\end{numcases}
$$
```

The `cases` packages relies on the `empheq` package, so you need to load both.  Also note that the `\tag` should go **before** the `\\` otherwise it will apply to the **next** line of the alignment.